# Java: How to use AccessControllerContext?

Tags: java, plugins, classloader

I am trying to design a plugin framework that will sandbox loaded plugins so that they can only perform risky actions through my plugin interfaces.

I need to figure out how to use AccessControllerContext to see what code is calling the methods.

The documentation shows no way to recover the code source or originating class. How can this be done?

Is it possible to set the context for all classes loaded from a particular class loader?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using an AccessControlContext directly, you should use [AccessController.checkPermission](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#checkPermission%28java.security.Permission%29), which will check the active security context for you.  To control what permissions are granted a class, use [ClassLoader.defineClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass%28java.lang.String,%20byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int,%20java.security.ProtectionDomain%29), and pass a [ProtectionDomain](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html) containing a [PermissionCollection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/PermissionCollection.html) with the appropriate set of permissions.  It might be useful to review an [Overview of Basic Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc2.html#19853) in the [Java Security Architecture](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/spec/security-spec.doc.html) document.

Comment: You can use `AccessControlContext.checkPermission` directly on a stored `AccessControlContext`.

Comment: Right, but why is the poster acquiring the ACC rather than using AC.doP in the first place?

Comment: What do you mean be "default acc"? `null` for `AccessControlContext` gives all permissions. `AccessController.getContext().checkPermission(perm)` is much the same as `AccessController.checkPermission(perm)`.